# Error in calculating resultant matrix in C programming language

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to write a program where I have two matrices and I multiply the two matrices and store it in a resultant matrix named "carr." For some weird reason, the matrix multiplication is not getting executed properly. Tried to find the issue for quite a while but couldn't find the error. Can anyone help? TIA for your time!
Here is the ss of the issue: https://snipboard.io/s9ifP4.jpg

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

int row1, column1, row2, column2,i,j,k, sum=0;

//START OF THE 1ST ARRAY//
printf("How many rows do you want for the first matrix? Ans: ");
scanf("%d", &row1);

printf("How many columns do you want for the first matrix? Ans: ");
scanf("%d", &column1);
int arr[row1][column1];

printf("Enter the elements of the first array:\n");
for(i = 0; i <row1; i++){
  for(j=0; j < column1; j++){

    scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
  }
}
printf("\n----------------------------------------\n");
printf("The elements of the first array are:\n");
for(i = 0; i <row1; i++){
  printf("[ ");
  for(j=0; j < column1; j++){
    printf("%d, ", arr[i][j]);
  }
  printf("]\n");
}
//END OF THE FIRST ARRAY//
printf("----------------------------------------\n");


//START OF THE 2ND ARRAY//
printf("\n**How many rows do you want for the second matrix?\n\nAlert: For matrix multiplication, the COLUMN of the 1st matrix MUST equal to the ROW of the 2nd matrix.\nAns: ");
scanf("%d", &row2);

printf("How many columns do you want for the second matrix? Ans: ");
scanf("%d", &column2);
int barr[row2][column2];

printf("Enter the elements of the second array:\n");
for(i = 0; i <row2; i++){
  for(j=0; j < column2; j++){

    scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
  }
}
printf("\n----------------------------------------\n");
printf("The elements of the second array are:\n");
for(i = 0; i <row2; i++){
  printf("[ ");
  for(j=0; j < column2; j++){
    printf("%d, ", arr[i][j]);
  }
  printf("]\n");
}
printf("----------------------------------------\n");
//END OF THE 2ND ARRAY//



//Everything above this part is okay. The problem starts from the Matrix multiplication part//

//MATRIX MULTIPLICATION//
//The resultant matrix where the values of the multiplied matrix is being held has row = ROW1 and column = COLUMN2.//
int carr[row1][column2];

if(column1 == row2)
{
for(i = 0; i < row1; i++){
  for(j=0; j < column2; j++){
    for(k=0; k < row2; k++){
      sum = sum + arr[i][k] * barr[k][j];
    }
    carr[i][j] = sum;
    sum=0;
  }
}
}

else
{
printf("Matrix multiplication is not possible");
}


printf("\n----------------------------------------\n");
printf("The elements of the resultant array are:\n");
for(i = 0; i <row1; i++){
  printf("[ ");
  for(j=0; j < column2; j++){
    printf("%d, ", carr[i][j]);
  }
  printf("]\n");
}
printf("----------------------------------------\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "TIA for your time!" -- You could save us some time by providing example input and by telling us which result you expect and which result you get.

Comment: When you read the second matrix, you read to `arr` instead of `barr`, leaving `barr` uninitialized.

Comment: Man, there is no expected output here. The main goal of this program is to find the resultant matrix of  the two matrices provided by the user. But the resultant matrix I get is totally garbage. You can have a look yourself.

Comment: Changed it to barr but even after changing  arr it to barr doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Here is the ss of the issue: https://snipboard.io/s9ifP4.jpg

Comment: Don't you get `[39, 38], [93, 106]` with the corrected code? (_That_ would be the expected answer.)

Comment: Yes, problem is fixed now. There was problem with the compiler. 
Thank you for your help, @MOehm

Answer (score 0):

Changing arr to barr fixes the issue. Thanks to @M Oehm for pointing out the error.